# Opencart 1.5 checkout confirm to payment gateway taking too much time

Tags: php, mysql, database, opencart

I'm running Opencart 1.5.6 with Journal Theme and i notice a serious issue on checkout page
after i click on the confirm order button it take about 30 second to reach the payment gateway
and this kill most of sales customers quit before :(

I notice this not happen when i'm already connected with all my infos.

It's like on checkout/checkout
taking very long time to write customers infos on database but i'm not sure if it's the problem.

I try to desactived the cache from Journal module but nothing change.

In Past i found that when we click on 
confirm button Opencart was trying to send first order email and this was terrible taking too much time so i remove it
and recover about 7/10 second so not bad!  but now can't find what cause this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and add Indexes in your Database Tables. Without Indexes the database operations becomes terribly slow. So you can try that. We have faced such issue in the past for Opencart and adding Indexes improved the speed a lot. Hope that helps.

Comment: i already try it but still same issue it happen only on registration and update order

Answer (score 0):

Solved i was using mail in admin setting i make a try using smtp and now everything is fast less 3 second to reach payment gateway before was sometime more 30 second same thing for update orders